# php ebs payment gateway integration -DR attribute value is missing

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am integrating EBS payment API using php in my website. I have integrated all the things, which the EBS document says.

But when I am writing code in `response.php` file, it is asking for DR attribute value. But I am very confused what would be the syntax of DR attribute?

Documentation says DR values would be combination of `Account ID`, `Mode`, `Return URL`, `Sale Amount`, `Description`, `Reference
Number`, `Billing` & `Shipping Address`.

So is it necessary to use all the parameter values or we can select limited parameters?

My return url is as follows -

```
$return_url="http://websiteurl/response.php
```

I haven't pass any parameter.

If it is necessary to pass parameters in return url, so the syntax is as follows -

```
$return_url="http://websiteurl/response.php?AccountID=valOfAccId&Mode=valOfMode&SaleAmount=valOfSaleAmount&Description=valOfDescription&Reference=valOfReference
```

Is it correct way or not?

Comment: Improved grammar and removed unnecessary text.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I am non native English speaker, so pardon! But could you please answer my question. Any help would be great.